# Ending of a message

Tags: letter-writing

I have to send an invitation to students in their final practicum process. Is it righ to end my message with " I expect to see you all"? The truth is that they MUST attend the meeting.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd say "Attendance is not optional - I expect you all to be there."

Comment: If they know the truth that they MUST attend it, "I expect to see you all as your attendance is required" will not sound wrong to them.

Comment: If you're just being polite with the closing, "Looking forward to seeing you there."  If you want to reemphasize the attendance requirement, though, something like what Rathony said.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of compulsoriness (I just checked -- that is a word) hinges on what you are expecting.

"I expect to see you." places your expectation on yourself.

"I expect you to attend." places your expectation on the others.

The confusion can arise because 'seeing' is usually considered to be an involuntary action (unlike for example looking).

Therefore in purely logical terms the above two sentences could be argued to be equivalent but in terms of the effect they have on the reader, the second is *much* stronger.

Comment: I think you have a compulsion towards sesquipedalianness.

Comment: @HotLicks, I pride myself in my sesquipedalianality. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Final "practicum" process sounds serious and the invitees would know they need to attend it without your explicitly saying so.

However, it is not wrong to put more explicitly:

> I expect to see you all as your attendance is required to successfully finish the practicum process.

[Required](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/required) means:

> Officially compulsory, or otherwise considered essential;
>   indispensable:

You could consider using "necessary" in place of "required" if you think it sounds too formal, or "mandatory" if it doesn't sound formal enough.

Comment: @JHCL Thank you for your suggestion. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> I look forward to seeing you for this essential part of your practicum process.

Sounds good to me.

Comment: I received this comment from someone  who bought something in internet " No home button though"

Comment: Maybe it is an idiom. how can I interpret it?

Comment: I'm assuming they mean there is no link back to the home page of the website. Seems a bit uconnected with this question though.